# Looping trough a list of objects in lua

Tags: oop, lua

I'm writing lua to script inside a videogame called Dual Universe, I'm trying to loop trough an array filled with objects and call their methods but it seems to turn my objects into numbers for some reason.

Here is the error message: attempt to index a number value (local 'projectile')
it's in the for loop of ProjectileGroup:move(), where I call projectile:move().

```
--Projectile class
Projectile = {x = 0, y = 0, z = 0, six = 0, siy = 0, siz = 0, spx = 0, spy = 0, spz = 0}
function Projectile:new (o,x,y,z,six,siy,siz,spx,spy,spz)
   o = o or {}
   setmetatable(o, self)
   self.__index = self
   self.x = x
   self.y = y
   self.z = z
   self.six = six
   self.siy = siy
   self.siz = siz
   self.spx = spx
   self.spy = spy
   self.spz = spz
   return o
end

function Projectile:move ()
   self.x = self.x + self.spx
   self.y = self.y + self.spy
   self.z = self.z + self.spz
end

function Projectile:log ()
    system.print('x: '..tostring(self.x)..'|y: '..tostring(self.y)..'|z: '..tostring(self.z)..'|six :'..tostring(self.six)..'|siy :'..tostring(self.siy)..'|siz :'..tostring(self.siz)..'|spx :'..tostring(self.spx)..'|spy :'..tostring(self.spy)..'|spz :'..tostring(self.spz))
end


--ProjectileGroup
ProjectileGroup = {projectiles=0}

function ProjectileGroup:new (o,projectiles)
   o = o or {}
   setmetatable(o,self)
   self.__index = self
   self.projectiles = projectiles
   return o
end

function ProjectileGroup:add_projectile(projectile)
    table.insert(self.projectiles, projectile)
end

function ProjectileGroup:move()
    for projectile in pairs(self.projectiles) do
        projectile:move()
    end
end

function ProjectileGroup:log()
    for projectile in pairs(self.projectiles) do
        projectile:log()
    end
end


projectileA = Projectile:new(nil,0,0,0,10,10,10,0.1,0.3,0.4)
projectileB = Projectile:new(nil,0,0,0,10,10,10,0.4,0.2,-0.4)
projectileC = Projectile:new(nil,0,0,0,10,10,10,0.1,0.05,0.1)
projectileGroup = ProjectileGroup:new(nil,{projectileA,projectileB,projectileC})
projectileGroup:move()
```

Comment: Replace `for projectile in pairs` with `for _, projectile in pairs`

Comment: In addition to what Egor said, you might want to use `ipairs` if you know that it's a list. This guarantees that you'll iterate the items in list order (although in practice `next` will do the same thing).

Comment: and check your tables. you're confusing `self` and `o`. Your `new` functions return empty tables with the same metatable. That's not what you want.